# Limiting azure container access to app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances

I have a resource group on Azure with a web application hosted as an App Service, that uses an Azure SQL Database and storage container for blob storage.

Within the storage account, I want to limit public access within the networking section, to only be enabled from selected virtual networks or IP addresses. If I enable this, I then need to provide access from my App Service within the same resource group. The most appropriate route seems to be by allowing access to resource instance, by adding a resource type by instance name. However, in the drop down list of resource types, there does not seem to be an option for App Service. Is this possible?

I considered allowing specific IP addresses, but the Microsoft documentation suggests that resources in the same region as the storage account use private Azure IP addresses for communication.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you **use the private endpoints section since this works almost in the same way as the ‘Resource instance’ type to be selected in the instance name since you want to restrict access to a system-managed assigned identity-based solution like an ‘App service’ wherein the web application is hosted in it**.

Thus, for this purpose, **you will have to create a private endpoint as shown below with the virtual network deployed in the same region as the storage account as well as the in the same resource group**. This will *`ensure that the private endpoint connection is traversing exclusively through the Microsoft backbone network only. Also, the private DNS zone that is created post creating a private endpoint for the respective blob container or any storage resource that you choose will host the DNS records for that respective storage account resource`*.

To create a private endpoint, kindly refer to the below snapshots for reference: -

[image: Private endpoint creation]

[image: Private endpoint creation - 2]

Similarly, in the **‘App Services’** section, you will have to **associate the private endpoint created as above in the respective virtual network as shown below. This will ensure that your private endpoint for the storage account resource is selected correctly as above**.

[image: Private endpoint connections]

•   Therefore, in the **‘Microsoft Resource Instance’** section in the storage account, *`you do not have ‘Microsoft App Services’ as an option by design itself, but through the implementation of private endpoint, we can surely achieve the same as required`*. Also, **ensure to check the option for ‘Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account’ as the service ‘Microsoft.AppServices/service’ is in the list of trusted services according to official documentation**.

Please find the below links for more details regarding the configuration private endpoint and the Microsoft resource instances in the storage account: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-trusted-azure-services***

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/41129/app-service-to-access-storage-account-with-firewal.html***